# Tracing the forward use of values in formulas in Numbers

Tags: applications, numbers

I use Numbers version 3.1 on Mavericks.

One can easily look at a formula in a given cell and immediately see the other cell references it uses.  I think of this as a backwards look.

Does any means or mechanism exist to do this forward rather than backwards?  By this I mean, can I trace the uses of a value or calculation in a cell as the propagate forward (typically down or to the right) through a spreadsheet - what formulas will use it rather than have used it.

I have used other spreadsheets, which had such a feature,  I just can't find it in Numbers.

If anyone knows how to do this please advise.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are referring to the formula relationship tool available in Excel:

[image]

I don't believe this feature is available in Numbers. You can notify Apple that you would like this feature implemented using their Numbers feedback page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html